# How to specific table schema for alembic_version when using flask-migrate

Tags: alembic

I using flask-migrate with PostgreSQL, when I execute `python manage.py db upgrade` command it will generate **alembic_version** table in **public** schema. How can I change the default schema when generate the **alembic_version** table?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a [version_table_schema](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.version_table_schema) argument to the `configure()` call. You can edit this in the `env.py` file.