# Alembic & Postgres: how to switch to another schema

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I have a postgres database with default `public` schema, which hosts some tables, including alembic migrations table.

I want a postgres database with an `app` schema, with all the tables (including alembic migrations) moved there.

How can I do this using Alembic migrations in concert with sqlalchemy and whatever settings change?

I found some info in related questions: [SQLAlchemy + alembic: create schema migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582020/sqlalchemy-alembic-create-schema-migration) and [How to specific table schema for alembic_version when using flask-migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316280/how-to-specific-table-schema-for-alembic-version-when-using-flask-migrate) and [Create an alembic migration to create schema for version_table_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205919/create-an-alembic-migration-to-create-schema-for-version-table-schema), but I'm strugginling to put them together in one (or two) neat migration + code changes.

I think it would be nice to have a recipe here, and I intend to post it myself in a day or so, if no one saves me from this nuisance :)

Answer (score 5):

All right, here it goes. The tricky part is to migrate the `alembic_version` table, as it is read before the migration and written to after. Also there are couple of places things need to be configured.

### First commit

First commit is for preparation. Wherever is you `Base` defined, change it to

`base.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema='public'))
```

Then modify the alembic env (thanks [h4](https://gist.github.com/h4/fc9b6d350544ff66491308b535762fee)!) to match this:

`env.py`

```py
[...]

context.configure(
    connection=connection,
    target_metadata=target_metadata,
    version_table_schema=target_metadata.schema,
    include_schemas=True,
)

with context.begin_transaction():
    context.execute(f'create schema if not exists {target_metadata.schema};')
    context.execute(f'set search_path to {target_metadata.schema}')
    context.run_migrations()

[...]
```

### Second commit

Create a new alembic migration

`2d8cec1e2a62_rename_schema.py`

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

[...]

def upgrade():
    if 'app' not in sa.inspect(op.get_bind()).get_schema_names():
        op.execute('alter schema public rename to app')
        op.execute('create schema public')
        op.execute('create table public.alembic_version AS (select * from app.alembic_version)')
    else:
        op.execute('drop table public.alembic_version')


def downgrade():
    pass
```

Commit **and run migration!**

### Third commit

Change the schema in `base.py` to `'app'`:

`base.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema='app'))
```

Commit and run migration.